# `E_FAIL` when creating DirectX 10 Device and Swap Chain - _com_error

Tags: c++, directx

I am working though some simple DX tutorials, and have hit an early snag. I am working on both an old laptop and a new PC, so I'm using d3d10_1.lib which lets me use a 9 feature set. The PC, however, does support all the way to DX11, so nothing should be a problem on there.

So here's the function where it fails:

```
bool DirectX9Renderer::Initialise(HWND* handle)
{
    //window handle
    hWnd = handle;

    //get window dimensions
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect( *hWnd, &rc );
    UINT width = rc.right - rc.left;
    UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(swapChainDesc));

    //set buffer dimensions and format
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;;

    //set refresh rate
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;

    //sampling settings
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;

    //output window handle
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = *hWnd;
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = true;    

    HRESULT result = D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain1( // this is line 57
        NULL, 
        D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL, 
        D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED | D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG,
        D3D10_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1,
        D3D10_1_SDK_VERSION,
        &swapChainDesc, 
        &pSwapChain,
        &pD3DDevice
    );
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return FatalError("D3D device creation failed");
    }

            // there's more stuff after this, but I don't get that far
    }
```

So the call to `D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain1` fails with the less-helpful error code `E_FAIL`.

There is a line in the Debug output too:

```
First-chance exception at 0x770f56c4 in TileTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00b6e8d4..
```

I have tried using `D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE` and different `D3D10_FEATURE_LEVEL_xx` values, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you turn on Debug output in the DirectX control panel? It should give you a more useful debug spew.

Comment: I have now, for 10/11, but the options on the DirectX9 tab are all greyed out.

Comment: D3D10_1_SDK_VERSION should be D3D10_SDK_VERSION as feature level 9...

Comment: The class is named DirectX9Renderer but you create a D3D10 device? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may have been to do with the `D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_FLAG` I sent in. I changed the `D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED | D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` to `0` and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create the device inside a VMware virtual machine. It failed (device stayed NULL) until I changed the requested FEATURE_LEVEL from `D3D10_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1` to `D3D10_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3`. I've heard this also helps other PCs with real hardware.